# Bokeh patches z order

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a number of patches with associated z values, and I'd like them to display so that if two patches overlap the one with the higher z value is shown.  It seems that the way to do this is by ordering the renderers according to this github conversation: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/696

I have done this successfully by applying a series of glyphs using `patch` in order of their z value. Unfortunately, using `patch` for all 460 glyphs takes 25 seconds for a response so it isn't a viable solution.

How do I change the render order for `patches`?  I tried ordering the input data, but this didn't seem to have an impact.

edit:
It seems there might not be a way to accomplish what I want.  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3601

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.12.10` patch draw order is always stable (see [`#7049`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/7049) for details). Therefore the answer is: upgrade to Bokeh `0.12.10` or newer and put the data in the orer you would like it to be drawn.